# Is it possible to implement django login-authentication with out writing my own template?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-authentication

my project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

and, my app url's are:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', django.contrib.auth.views.logout, {'template_name': 'logout.html'}, name='logout'),
]
```

I'm learning about django authentication. As after reading some docs, I've made a sample app and tried to implement the django authentication system on it.

Is there any built-in django template for these built in views. I've tried it without writing my own template but it throws exception. When I add my login template it works fine.

Is it possible to implement django-authentication with out writing my own `'login.html'` template? Is django really having any built-in one? If it is, then how can I include it in my app?

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Django does not come with a login template. From the [authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views):

> It’s your responsibility to provide the html for the login template, called registration/login.html by default.

If Django came with a login template, it would probably look basic. Django doesn't know template structure, so wouldn't be able to inherit from your base template. So most people would end up creating a custom login template anyway. However, it would be easier for new users if Django included a template, however basic it looked.

Note that the [authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) includes a sample template that you can use.

As an aside, you should either include 'django.contrib.auth.urls', or add entries for login and logout to your app's urls (this allows you to override the template name). You don't need to do both.